# LINQ Multiple Filtering Fastest Way

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql

This Code will be called through the object data source within the asp.net application.
In northwind database , there exist a table with name of Customer. so I want to filter the grid view like below :

[image]

as you can see in image above , there are two drop downs at top of the grid view . they will filter the Gridview with ContactTitle and Country Columns , So , I have written the code In DAL Like Below :

```
var q = (from customers in db.Customers
                         select new
                         {
                             customers.ContactName,
                             customers.ContactTitle,
                             customers.City,
                             customers.Country,
                             customers.Phone,
                             customers.Address
                         });
            if (!country.Equals("All")) q = q.Where(e => e.Country == country);
            if (!contactTitle.Equals("All")) q = q.Where(e => e.ContactTitle == contactTitle);
```

So the code works nice , but this code will call the database connection three times ! One for selecting all , Second for filtering country and third Time for filtering with contact Title , How Can I Optimize this queries into One query ?

My Second Question is : How Can I Delete Duplicated Values in Drop downs with out querying again ? I don't want to use select Distinct or other query .... Can I have something like this :
(Note DropDowns are Binded to database...)

```
OnDataBind (e) {
  if(!DropDown1.Contains(e.value)) DropDown1.Add(e.Value);
}
```

UPDATE :

var q = (from customers in db.Customers
             where (country.Equals("All") || customers.Country == country ) &&
                   (contactTitle.Equals("All") || customers.ContactTitle == contactTitle)

```
             select new
             {
                 customers.ContactName,
                 customers.ContactTitle,
                 customers.City,
                 customers.Country,
                 customers.Phone,
                 customers.Address
             });
```

The code above will do the same but not faster , because the first code is Linq To Object !

Comment: Do your queries return `IQueryable<>`?

Comment: Yes , return type is IQueryable !

Comment: In that case your code should be fine as it is as you're not actually executing the query yet.  You can confirm this by looking at your `q` var while debugging.

Comment: from statement will executed the query !

Comment: Strange - I use that technique all the time to minimise db calls.

Comment: I have found that , I will post my answer at next post